# Building wheels for collected packages: torch-sparse takes a lot of time colab

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, pytorch-geometric

I am looking at this colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/132hNQ0voOtTVk3I4scbD3lgmPTQub0KR?usp=sharing#scrollTo=hNERp-_xs27y

It uses Pytorch Geometric Temproal for temporal GNN training.
I am wondering if there are ways to fasten the execution of the second cell, which ontains commands to install the needed libraries. It took about 1h30 to execute for me.

Furthermore, the code in this cell successfully installs the needed libraries only when the instance is a GPU one. Otherwise, the imports in the 3rd cell give the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_geometric.utils.to_dense_adj'
```

Any suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0):

After using `pip install torch-sparse`, I encountered the same thing. Some people say to keep the packages on the drive.

But try using this cell instead. I tried it and it worked.

```py
import torch

!pip uninstall torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-geometric torch-cluster  --y
!pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html
!pip install git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git
```